# How do I get 2 Flash banners to wait until both are loaded?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I have two Flash banner ads, built in CS5.5, using AS2, that will be placed on a page together and appear to interact with each other when played at the same time. Similar to this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X8YG6cL3ngY

The problem is that they might not load at the same time. How can I get each banner to check that the other has finished loading before playing?

I had read that LocalConnection was the way to do this, but I haven't been able to find anything that explains it well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First hit on Google has some code examples - at least try it and post if you get stuck - http://test.adform.com/testpage/banner-specifications/rich-media-instructions/synchronized-banners/

Comment: Although first check that your ad serving company do not have a solution already for this. The ones I work with (MediaMind, DoubleClick) provide components to make syncronizing banners easy.

Comment: Dan that helped a bit, but I'm stuck now. I tried setting it up to send code from my Big Box to my Leaderboard. The code in the Big Box is:

`stop();
var BigBoxSend = new LocalConnection();
this.onLoad = function() {
BigBoxSend.send("BigBoxConnection","BigBoxPlay");
}`

The code in the Leaderboard is:

`stop();
var LetterboxReceive = new LocalConnection();
LetterboxReceive.BigBoxPlay = function(){
play();
}
LetterboxReceive.connect("BigBoxConnection");`

I load the page and the Leaderboard starts playing fine. Hit refresh and won't play. Hit refresh again and it plays. Hit it again and it wont

Comment: Ok, the above issue only affects Firefox (maybe only on Mac?), not Safari, Chrome, or IE. Also of note is if it's open in one browser, it won't work in another. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this question has been asked when flash animations were allowed in Browsers.But  I just would like to give a small clue that local connection between iframes also possible on html5 banners and also canvas animated banners created with Adobe Animate, css animated banners or video banners. 
Simply follow instructions here: [connection between iframes](http://www.emresakarya.de/local-connection/)